# Word. Как занумеровать страницы с разной ориентацией

Tags: ms-word

Имеется документ Word-2007, часть страниц в котором имеет книжную ориентацию, часть альбомную. Как занумеровать страницы, что бы номер при подшивке распечатанного документа находился в одном углу. Разбивка на несколько отдельных документов не вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден. Нужно выполнить следующую последовательность действий:

1. Разбить документ на отдельные разделы, так что бы ориентация страниц внутри раздела совпадала.
2. В свойствах колонтитула, каждого раздела, обязательно убрать галку "Как в предыдущем разделе"
3. В "книжных" разделах в колонтитул, просто вставляем номер страницы.
4. В "альбомных" разделах, в нижний колонтитул, вставляем таблиц, задаем в таблице выравнивание и направление текста, убираем границы, в ячейку таблицы делаем `Вставка > Номер страницы > В текущее положение`. Немножко играемся размерами и положением таблицы.

...

5. PROFIT